# Automatically generate an account from contact with a button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a button to my contacts that when pressed, it will automatically create a account with the contact fields. I have the next code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/apex.js")}
var act = new sforce.SObject("Account");
act.Name = {!Contact.Name };
act.Phone = {!Contact.Phone};
act.Type = "Personal";
var result = sforce.connection.create([act]);
if(result[0].getBoolean("success")){
window.location = "/" + result[0].id + "/e";
}else{
alert('Could not create record '+result);
}
```

But it give me the error "A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: Unexpected identifier", and I'm out of ideas. Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you need to ensure that the merge fields are interpreted as JavaScript strings by adding quotes:

```
act.Name = "{!Contact.Name }";
act.Phone = "{!Contact.Phone}";
```

(Its worth using "View Source" in the generated page to check the output and ensure it looks like valid JavaScript.)

Comment: Oh god, how could I missed that?! Solved! Thanks a lot!